# Use jenkins with mercurial and google code

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, continuous-integration, google-code

I'm trying to use jenkins on my google code project of
but I have the following problem when I do a build

I downloaded the google code plugin but doesnt work :(

`Started by an SCM change`
`Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Zipper/workspace`
`$ hg clone --rev default --noupdate http://code.google.com/p/zipper-beta/source /checkout/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Zipper/workspace`
`abort: error: No such file or directory`
`ERROR: Failed to clone http://code.google.com/p/zipper-beta/source/checkout`
`ERROR: Failed to clone http://code.google.com/p/zipper-beta/source/checkout`
`Sending e-mails to: gabriel.lozano@miorg.org`
`Finished: FAILURE`

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is incorrect. The plugin is doing:

```
hg clone --rev default --noupdate http://code.google.com/p/zipper-beta/source
```

while it should do:

```
hg clone --rev default --noupdate http://code.google.com/p/zipper-beta
```

or even

```
hg clone --rev default --noupdate https://code.google.com/p/zipper-beta  (with https)
```